# 3 pairs, FX options, implied vols

Tags: options, fx, volatility-skew

I am trying to undertand the relationship between EUR/JPY options and USD/EUR and USD/JPY options.
Vol(USD/EUR) = $S_1$, Vol(Usd/JPY) = $S_2$, Vol(EUR/JPY) = $S_3$
The actual Vol follows:
\begin{align}
S_3^2 = S_1^2 + S_2^2 - 2 \rho(S_1,S_2) S_1 S_2
\end{align}

where $\rho$ is the implied correlation. But looking at the skew of EUR/JPY and trying the above formula, there are differences along the skew, i.e. different correlation or "implied correlation".
Question is, can someone explain intuitively why the implied correlation is skewed?

Comment: The above formulas assume GBM and BS with a single vol characterising each distribution. In BS, there is no vol skew, so trying to compare skews from market data is not consistent with your model.

Comment: Thanks StackG, so if I want to price EUR/JPY options using only USD/EUR and USD/JPY, how would you model it?

Comment: If you have some reading matterial it would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: The easiest way to take the skew into account is to use the fact that locally the variance relationship holds for each stochastic process. So you can use the local volatility surface of each underlying pair to get a market consistent local volatility surface for the cross pair. Once you have that its just solving the forward equation to get back all the option prices and thus the implied volatilities. However, if your cross pair has a liquid option market you will realize that this process doesn't return that surface and some kind of local correlation adjustment is required.